# add a new record into a table with an identity primary key

Tags: vb.net

I have this table structure in my database :

```
CREATE TABLE RIAD (
NumeroR int primary key identity,
 NomR varchar(50),
 AdresseRueR varchar(50),
 CodePostalR int,
  VilleR varchar(50),
 TelephoneR varchar(50),
 NomContactR varchar(50),
 CodeReg int,
 NombreDePlaces int)
```

and I have this form :

[image]

I want when I click on button Ajouter to add a new record into the table RIAD in my database from the text fields above the three butons.

this is the code I tried :

```
Public cnx As New SqlConnection("data source=localhost; initial catalog=EFF_TSDI_2009_V1; integrated security=sspi")
    Public ds As New DataSet
    Public adapterRiad As SqlDataAdapter
    Public builderRiad As SqlCommandBuilder

Private Sub MajRiad_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        adapterRiad = New SqlDataAdapter()
        adapterRiad.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM RIAD", cnx)
        adapterRiad.Fill(ds, "RIAD")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("RIAD")
        builderRiad = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapterRiad)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dialog As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Voulez vous vraiment ajouter cette personne ?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If (dialog = DialogResult.Yes) Then

            ds.Tables("RIAD").Rows.Add(nomR.Text, AdresseRueR.Text, CInt(CodePostalR.Text), VilleR.Text, TelephoneR.Text, NomContactR.Text, _
CInt(CodeReg.Text), CInt(NombreDePlaces.Text))
            For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
                If TypeOf (c) Is TextBox Then
                    c.Text = String.Empty
                End If
            Next
            adapterRiad.InsertCommand = builderRiad.GetInsertCommand
            adapterRiad.Update(ds, "RIAD")

        End If
    End Sub
```

But when I click on the button Ajouter I get this error :

> *Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store  in NumeroR Column.  Expected type is Int32.*

`<eeeee>` is the values I tried to write in the NomR text field, and VB.net is trying to save the new row with the value of NomR text field as the primary key, but the primary key is identity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the [Rows.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/07wwak56%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method you might want to explicitly state which field goes where...This is more code but stops the framework from making assumptions on your behalf.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) is a reference. The relevant section is "Inserting a New Record into an Untyped Dataset"

So you could do something like:

```
Dim newRiadRow As DataRow = ds.Tables("RIAD").NewRow()

newCustomersRow("NomR") = nomR.Text
newCustomersRow("AdresseRueR") = AdresseRueR.Text
'More fields here

ds.Tables("RIAD").Rows.Add(newRiadRow)
```